# Hibernate removal - Set replacement

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, persistence, set

I am removing Hibernate for a certain portion of our larger application where we have been seeing database contention and deadlocks that could never be isolated or recreated consistently.

Parent-child relationship, where the children are mapped in our `.hbm.xml` as a `Set`: Hibernate uses their own implementation of `Set` (specifically `PersistentSet`).

We do correctly/properly program against the `java.util.Set` interface in referencing a parent's children.

My question: Now that I need to pull out Hibernate, which implementation of `java.util.Set` is the most comparable (or best replacement in a non-Hibernate world) for Hibernate's `PersistentSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Hibernate's `PersistentSet` uses `java.util.HashSet` under the covers.  Thus, that would be the best replacement for `PersistentSet` when removing Hibernate.

[Hibernate 3.2 JavaDoc for `PersistentSet`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentSet.html)